# C# Remove unnecessary brackets, but leaving just the one

Tags: c#

I have the following string list of different sizes

```
[5].[1].[2].[3].[4].__class SetObjectModel
[5].[1].[4].__class SetObjectModel
[5].[1].[4].[3].[1].__class SetObjectModel
```

I need to remove all other brackets and just leave the first one:

```
[5].__class SetObjectModel
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve this?

Comment: This does not look like C# - is it the output of some debugger or decompiler?

Comment: If that is ALWAYS the format you can just split by period and concatenate the first and last element

Comment: Or are those _literal_ strings that you want to remove some of the text from? If so, I would enclose them in quotes.

Comment: It's the output file of a very old tool that generates logs from machinery failure. I've been tasked with writing a C# program that can interpret the logs and output this as a flatter file for another system to consume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a full sample of using the `Split` feature of a string and the `Join`.
You can read more about `Split` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) and `Join` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0)

```
// source list of string to modify
var source = new List<string>()
{
    "[5].[1].[2].[3].[4].__class SetObjectModel",
    "[5].[1].[4].__class SetObjectModel",
    "[5].[1].[4].[3].[1].__class SetObjectModel"
};

// convert each element of source into a result set
var results = source.Select(value =>
{
    // split by the period 
    var splitted = value.Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    // join the first and last element with a period to match the format you want
    return string.Join(".", new[] { splitted.First(), splitted.Last() });
}).ToList();
```

Here's the second portion of converting without using Linq and other quick 1 liner in case you are not familiar with them

```
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (string value in source)
{
    // split by the period
    string[] splitted = value.Split(new[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    // will contain the elements to keep and join
    List<string> elements = new List<string>();

    // add first element of the split
    elements.Add(splitted[0]);

    // add the last element of the split
    elements.Add(splitted[splitted.Length - 1]);

    // join the elements together
    string join = string.Join(".", elements);

    // add the join to the result set
    result.Add(join);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't even think to split this, but your code has solved my issue. P.s. results.Add(join) should be result.Add(join). Many thanks.